# Replacing stuff in JSON string

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

Why do I get an error with this:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"jsonRoster unmasked: %@", jsonString);
NSString *maskedString = [self maskJSON:jsonString withMultipleElementStartString:@"###multipleElementsBegin###" andMultipleEndString:@"###multipleElementsEnd###" andSingleElementStartString:@"###elementBegin###" andSingleElementEndString:@"###elementEnd###"];
NSLog(@"jsonRoster masked: %@", maskedString);
```

Here is the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI
>   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x600002932400'

But why, is the string still a Dictionary?

Comment: Did this start off as a JSON file? If this is the case, why don't you just read it from the file? Or do you also want validation on the file?

Comment: As schmidt9 mentioned, if you want a string from the data then use NSString's initWithData method to get the data converted to a string. Yes a json is a string traditionally, but JSONObjectWithData will give you an object that you can work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per error message `JSONObjectWithData` returned an `NSDictionary` object, in fact it is in practice so, `JSONObjectWithData` returns a dictionary or an array depending on your JSON structure. So you should normally check return type and handle it properly.

**Edit**
To get an `NSString` you can use its `initWithData:encoding:` method.

Comment: hm ok but how can I get the JSON as one single string? So I can send one single string to our server?

Comment: By using `NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8String]`, you can.